# Creating a Queue from LinkedList

Tags: java, queue

I have a problem with creating a Queue object.I dont know what is wrong.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();


    }
}
```

Compiler error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      The type LinkedList is not generic; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments

Comment: I am not getting any Compile time errors for this code on eclipse.

Comment: This is odd - LinkedList IS generic.  Do you have another LinkedList defined/imported somewhere?  Try Mohammad's solution below to force the compiler to use the correct LinkedList.

Comment: It is something related with your library..Use `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: I crated a new project now its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be a name conflict (*see if you have a class named LinkedList somewhere in your default package*)

Try this -

```
 Queue<Integer> q = new java.util.LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Comment: But why i need to do this?.If you see code given in question import is already being done

Comment: Can't say if OP has a class Named `LinkedList` somewhere

Comment: @Algorithmist: I suspect there's another class in the default package with the name `LinkedList`. But it's not clear what you mean by "But why I need to do this" - are you actually the original poster? If so, please don't use multiple accounts.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am not the poster of this question :). Now i am not able to edit my post. I used "I" mainly because i tried to write the same code on my eclipse after seeing this question and got no errors.